# strtotime return false, data from csv

Tags: php, strtotime

I tried to read date data from csv and tried to convert it to timestamp. reading csv process using fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t") is no problem. I pass the data to $created_time. But it returned false, when I try to convert to timestamp. what's wrong with the strtotime?

```
echo $created_time.'<br>';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($created_time)).'<br>';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2017-11-07T15:38:35+07:00")).'<br>';
```

output:

```
2017-11-07T15:38:35+07:00
1970-01-01 07:00:00 <== false
2017-11-07 15:38:35 <== correct same string, different source
```

UPDATE:
I couldn't find the problem. I bet it's about the encoding when parsing the csv. Anyway, I drop this function `fgetcsv` and use this library: https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

Comment: `var_dump("2017-11-07T15:38:35+07:00" == $created_time);` ?

Comment: Try using something like `addslashes`, `quotemeta` or `htmlspecialchars` to print `$created_time`. I'm pretty sure there's some funny characters that doesn't print, maybe `<br>`, in that string.

Comment: Could be that created_time is a type which isn't strictly a string, echo will typecast to a string if needed, so try `strtotime((string)$created_time)`

Comment: already tried `iconv`, `trim`, `rtrim`, `(string)`, `striplashes` nothing works. also no funny chars using the `addslashes`, `htmlspecialchars`. the `quotemeta` adds backslash tho.

Comment: `var_dump("2017-11-07T15:38:35+07:00" == $created_time);` this returns false. I think there's something wrong with the csv

Comment: @danuparta What is the output of `var_dump($created_time);`?

Comment: @danuparta does the parsecsv-for-php library solve your problem, or is it still happening?

Comment: @Progman, the output was false

Comment: @BarryMode yes, parsecsv-for-php library solved the problem.